# Cronometro entre duas datas AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, countdown

Suponhamos que tenho duas datas:
`2015-11-13T08:00:00` e `2015-11-13T10:00:00`, como podem ver tem uma diferença de duas horas entre essas datas. Gostaria de colocar um cronometro em minha view que mostre essa diferença.

Tentei adaptar esse exemplo: http://codepen.io/garethdweaver/pen/eNpWBb/.

Porém quando o altero ele para de funcionar.

Como faço esse cronometro, ou então por onde começar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei uma diretiva em **Angular JS** para isso:

```
 angular.module('iCountdown', [])
    .directive("iCountdown", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EAC",
            scope: {
                setStartDate: "@",
                setEndDate: "@",
                expireMessage: "@",
                startMessage: "@", 
                formatView: "@",
                setTemplateView: "@",
                consideredCurrentDate: "@",

            },
            replace: true,
            template: "<div><div></div></div>",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var insertDate = function() {
                    scope.setMessageExpired(scope.expireMessage);
                    scope.setMessageInitial(scope.startMessage);
                   if (angular.isDefined(scope.setStartDate) && angular.isDefined(scope.setEndDate)) {
                       params.dateStart = scope.setStartDate;
                       params.dateEnd = scope.setEndDate;
                       if (angular.isDefined(scope.setTemplateView)) {
                           params.templateView =  scope.setTemplateView;
                           params.activeCurrentDate = scope.consideredCurrentDate;
                       }
                    } 
                    scope.start();
                };

                scope.$watch('setDateEnd', function() {
                   insertDate();
                }, true);

                var _end = new Date();
                var _start = new Date();
                var _second = 1000;
                var _minute = _second * 60;
                var _hour = _minute * 60;
                var _day = _hour * 24;

                var params = {
                    second:_second,
                    minute:_minute,
                    hour: _hour,
                    day: _day,
                    interval: null,
                    messageFinal: 'expired!',
                    messageInitial: 'please whait...',
                    format:'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                    dateEnd: null,
                    dateStart: null,
                    currDate: null,
                    templateView: null,
                    activeCurrentDate:'false'
                };

                scope.getCurrentStartDate = function() {

                    var _dt = new Date();
                     var _current = [
                                 [_dt.getFullYear(),
                                  ((_dt.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0' + (_dt.getMonth()+1) : (_dt.getMonth()+1)),
                                  (_dt.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + _dt.getDate() : _dt.getDate())
                                 ].join('-'),
                                 [(_dt.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + _dt.getHours() : _dt.getHours()),
                                  (_dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + _dt.getMinutes() : _dt.getMinutes()),
                                  (_dt.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + _dt.getSeconds() : _dt.getSeconds())
                                 ].join(':')
                               ].join(' ');
                    return _current;

                }

                scope.setMessageExpired = function(message) {
                    params.messageFinal = message;
                };


                scope.setMessageInitial = function(message) {
                    params.messageInitial = message;
                };

                scope.setId = function(id) {
                    params.id = id;
                    scope.viewElement.setAttribute("id", id);
                };

                 scope.setDateStarter = function(strDate) {
                    params.protype.dateStart = strDate;
                };

                scope.setDateFinal = function(strDate) {
                   params.protype.dateEnd = strDate;
                };

               var createElementDate = function(strDate) {

                    var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
                    var dateArray = reggie.exec(strDate);
                    return new Date(
                        (+dateArray[1]),
                        (+dateArray[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
                        (+dateArray[3]),
                        (+dateArray[4]),
                        (+dateArray[5]),
                        (+dateArray[6])
                    );
                };

                scope.remaining = function() {
                    if (!params.currDate)
                    {
                       if (params.activeCurrentDate == 'true') {
                           params.dateStart = (createElementDate(scope.setStartDate).getTime() < createElementDate(scope.getCurrentStartDate()).getTime()) ? scope.getCurrentStartDate() : params.dateStart;
                       }
                        params.currDate = createElementDate(params.dateStart);
                    }

                    _start = params.currDate;
                    _end = createElementDate(params.dateEnd);

                    if (!(_end instanceof Date) || isNaN(_end.valueOf()) ) {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data final não foi definida,' +
                            ' adicione uma data conforme o exemplo: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss!';
                         return;
                    }
                    if (!(_start instanceof Date) || isNaN(_start.valueOf()) ) {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data inicial não foi definida,'+
                            ' adicione uma data conforme o exemplo: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss!';
                        return;
                    }

                     if (!params.currDate)
                    {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data inicial é inválida!';
                        return;
                    }
                    params.currDate.setSeconds(params.currDate.getSeconds() + 1);

                    var distance = _end - _start;

                    if (distance < 0) {
                        clearInterval(params.interval);
                        element[0].innerHTML = params.messageFinal;
                        return;
                    }
                    var i=0;
                    var checkInterval = setInterval(function() {
                      if (createElementDate(scope.getCurrentStartDate()).getTime() < createElementDate(scope.setStartDate).getTime()) {
                      element[0].innerHTML = params.messageInitial;
                      return;
                      } else {
                         clearInterval(checkInterval);
                      }
                    },1);

                    var days = Math.floor(distance / params.day);
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % params.day) / params.hour);
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % params.hour) / params.minute);
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % params.minute) / params.second);
                    var elementsTime = [];
                    elementsTime[0] =((days < 10) ? '0' : '') + days;
                    elementsTime[1] =((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours;
                    elementsTime[2] =((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
                    elementsTime[3] =((seconds < 10) ? '0' : '') + seconds;
                    element[0].innerHTML =  scope.setFormatViewTime(elementsTime);

                };

                scope.setFormatViewTime = function(elementsTime) {
                    var view = scope.formatView
                        .replace(/%d/gi, elementsTime[0])
                        .replace(/%h/gi, elementsTime[1])
                        .replace(/%i/gi, elementsTime[2])
                        .replace(/%s/gi, elementsTime[3]);

                    if(angular.isDefined(params.templateView) && params.templateView != null && params.templateView != "") {
                        return params.templateView.replace(/%t/gi, view);
                    } else {
                       return view; 
                    }
                };

                scope.setFormatDate = function(format) {
                    params.format = format;
                };

                scope.start = function () {

                    if (!(_end instanceof Date) || isNaN(_end.valueOf()) ) {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data final não foi definida, '+
                            'adicione uma data conforme o exemplo: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss!';
                         return;
                    }
                    if (!(_start instanceof Date) || isNaN(_start.valueOf()) ) {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data inicial não foi definida, '+
                            'adicione uma data conforme o exemplo: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss!';
                        return;
                    }
                    if (_start > _end) {
                        element[0].innerHTML = 'A data inicial não pode ser maior que a data final!';
                        return;
                    }
                    params.interval = setInterval(this.remaining, params.second);


                };
            }
        };
    });
```

A diretiva no HTML:

```
<div ng-app="iCountdown">
<i-countdown set-start-date="2015-11-13 10:58:00"
             set-end-date="2015-11-13 13:18:00"
             format-view="%d dias %h hs %i min %s sg"
             expire-message="Fim de jogo"
             start-message="Aguarde o início"
             considered-current-date="true"
             set-template-view="<div id='elemento'>%t</div>">
</i-countdown>
</div>
```

## Aqui o exemplo funcionando

Comment: Opa, analisando a diretiva creio que ela irá anteder minha necessidade. Porém só uma dúvida, como uso ela direto no controller passando as duas datas como parâmetro?

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Uma ultima dúvida, se eu quiser mudar a cor da mensagem de "fim" de jogo onde tenho que alterar?

Comment: cara, vc embute uma template. nessa template vc passa id class, etc...
http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1cyxoytv/48/ vc pode passar a mensagem como  html "<p class='tema'/>fim do jogo</p>".

Comment: A sim, entendi. Valeu :D

Answer (score 2):

Instanciando new Date você pode ter um código mais limpo, como o que eu fiz:
No projeto que utilizei precisei somar o timezone também. O vm antes da variável é o controller `var vm = this;`

```
    vm.dataInicial = undefined;
    vm.cronometro = '00:00:00';

    vm.tick = function() {
        if(vm.dataInicial) {
            var dataAgora = Date.now();
            var timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

            vm.cronometro = new Date(new Date(dataAgora).getTime() - new Date(vm.dataInicial).getTime());
            vm.cronometro.setMinutes(vm.cronometro.getMinutes() + timezone);
        }
        $timeout(vm.tick, 1000);
    };

    $timeout(vm.tick, 1000);
```

Quando eu consulto um atendimento pendente e preciso da data inicial diferente de `Date.now()` eu faço a linha abaixo:

```
vm.dataInicial = new Date(parseInt(response.data.DataInicio.substr(6)));
```

No HTML ficou bem simples de chamar:

```
<h3 ng-show="vm.atendimentoIniciado && vm.dataInicial" style="color: #8E0000">{{vm.cronometro | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</h3>
```